# Why do I need to install Nvidia driver for Flatpak applications?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, flatpak

When I want to install an application from flatpak repository, it shows that flatpak also needs to install Nvidia driver.

I've read about Flatpak in the flatpak documentation web site and it seems to have sandbox system and applications can only run in an isolated environment:

[image: Flatpak Sandbox]

I have two questions:

1. Is Nvidia driver needed to be used inside the sandbox? Why flatpak applications need to have Nvidia driver when we have Nvidia driver installed on our system. Isn't the main graphical driver responsible for drawing on the screen at last? If flatpack driver works separably due to the sandbox system, how it works alongside with the main driver?
2. Does flatpak Nvidia driver replace the driver that is installed on my system?

Answer (score 9):

Flatpak applications run in a sandboxed environment, where they can't access the outside world. That's why a separate copy of the driver needs to be installed.

Due to the fact it's sandboxed, it won't replace the system driver. It just supplements it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I want to know more, Isn't the main graphical driver responsible for drawing on the screen at last? If flatpack driver works separably due to the sandbox system, how it works alongside with main driver?

Comment: @ICE They both work together, parts of the driver are in userspace and parts in kernel land.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos If the userspace driver has newer features or better performance, will flatpaks apps take advantage of them?

Comment: @jayarmstrong `flatpak update` will always attempt to make sure the Flatpak'd driver and the host driver versions are in sync, i.e. any new features the host driver has should be available in the Flatpak as well